# Colour of Text in a Javascript Alert

Tags: javascript, css, alerts

Is there any way to change style of text, format the text inside a Javascript Alert box. e.g. changing its colour, making it bold, etc.?

Also, if there an Alert avalaible with a 'Yes', 'No' button instead of an 'OK'/'Cancel' one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**No**, I'm afraid that is not possible.

With JavaScript, you are limited to only 3 popup boxes: `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm`.

If you want to make a more featured popup, you should try using one of the many that exist written in JavaScript, which are built from JavaScript Libraries, such as [this](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

Comment: Thanks! I guessed so, just wanted to confirm with the community, in case I had been ignorant. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do for formatting is the new line character `\n`.

Comment: It's not much, but it's something! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate the standard alert dialogs this way, but you can make your own ones and style them however you like.

Check out the custom dialog tutorial on [slayeroffice.com](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/) for an example on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/ this is your man... runs on top of prototype and has AJAX, drag and drop and lots of thing ready waiting for you =)