# How to display Yes/No Button in asp.net page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, confirmation

I have to display yes/no button on some condition on my asp.net page , I used windows.confirm() to display that but windows.confirm displays Ok/Cancel Button , Is there any way I can display Yes/No Button in asp.net page instead of Ok/Cancel using Javascript ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391143/colour-of-text-in-a-javascript-alert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, just check some of the jQuery or YUI plugins, you can get that up and running with a couple of lines of code.

For example, [this one](http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal/) uses jQuery and [this one](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/simpledialog-quickstart.html) uses YUI.

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/groups/javascript/149838-yes-no-dialog-box-javascript

Read there :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the button text on a JavaScript alert, and while you can't change them on a VBScript message box, it has different text.  How I got around this was to develop a custom div that contains buttons with the correct text on them that is displayed using absolute positioning and a shadow effect to give the appearance of a message box.

Answer (score 0):

not cross browser without creating an custom modal dialong or using one that is already built.  if you can use ms ajax then it has a modal you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using prompt, you can show a hidden div with html controls and javascript wired up to buttons.  When you want to ask the question show the previously hidden div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

JS code:
`if(confirm('Are you sure???')){
{

}else{

}`